# Expand image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a task to create a new double sized blank image and then to fill every second row and column with the rows and columns of the original image. 
Here's my solution, but it doesn't work (there are some advices for this task in comments and there's a gaussian filter for an expand):

```
A = im2double(imread('orange.png'));

gA = expand(A);

function g = expand(I)

% Input:
% I: the input image
% Output:
% g: the image after the expand operation
% Please follow the instructions to fill in the missing commands.    
% 1) Create the expanded image. 
% The new image should be twice the size of the original image.
% So, for an n x n image you will create an empty 2n x 2n image
% Fill every second row and column with the rows and columns of the original image
% i.e., 1st row of I -> 1st row of expanded image
%       2nd row of I -> 3rd row of expanded image
%       3rd row of I -> 5th row of expanded image, and so on


[height,width,coef] = size(I);
new = ones(height * 2,width * 2,coef);
for c=1:coef
    for m=1:height
        for n=1:width
            new(m * 2 - 1,n * 2 - 1,c) = I(m,n,c);
        end
    end
end


% 2) Create a Gaussian kernel of size 5x5 and 
% standard deviation equal to 1 (MATLAB command fspecial)
gas = fspecial('gaussian', [5 5], 1);
% 3) Convolve the input image with the filter kernel (MATLAB command imfilter)
% Tip: Use the default settings of imfilter
% Remember to multiply the output of the filtering with a factor of 4


g = imfilter(new,gas) .* 4;
end
```

Can you give me an advice if there's some native function for this in matlab or how to perform this action?

Thank You

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? It seems okay other than you might want to change `ones()` to `zeros()` and you might be creating `new` with a different data type than `I`.

Comment: @beaker thank you. But i quite don't understand about creating new with a different data type

Comment: I'm just guessing because you haven't told us what the actual problem is. Why do you say your solution doesn't work? Does it give you an error? Are you getting wrong results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct, apart from, as beaker said, having ones(height * 2,width * 2,coef) instead of zeros(height * 2,width * 2,coef);.

Try this for conciseness though. Sometimes, longer code makes it tricky to catch minor typos.

```
function g = expand(I)

[height,width,coef] = size(I);
new = zeros(height * 2,width * 2,coef);
new(1:2:end,1:2:end,1:end) = I;    

gas = fspecial('gaussian', [5 5], 1);


g = imfilter(new,gas) .* 4;
```

Comment: Wow, it really works! I didn't suspect that ones is the problem. But why is it a problem? We change all the values in the loop

Comment: It might depend on the range of your image data.